# Drool decision table evaluating boolean function

Tags: drools

I have written a function in a Drools xlsx file, but it is behaving weirdly. My function `check123()` is returning a boolean value in the condition, but my action is called when function `check123()` returns `false`, and when it returns `true` the action is not executing. In normal condition it is working fine.

[image: Decision table]

Can someone explain what's going on, and how to fix it?

Comment: If you change cell `D11` to be `check123($param, ec)`, does it work?

Comment: yes but still same issue , i runes for both ,I think is it parsing issue ,becoz i am working in libra office, what do you think?